# Why is VBA suddenly throwing a runtime error 457 on a dictionary item using a dynamic String variable as a key?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, runtime-error

I have been running the following VBA code in Excel for the last several days and suddenly, I started getting the following error:

"Run-time error 457:
This key is already associated with an element of this collection",

always identifying the [infantry_dic.Add cell_str, subCell_str] line as the problem, even if I comment out all the other dictionary and collection .Add calls.  Interestingly, when I first run a backup file, I don't get an error, but on subsequent runs, without changing anything, the error message returns.  Is this some sort of persistent memory issue?  I restarted and even shut down my laptop computer, but the problem persists.

The code is very simple, and even backups that were working are now not working without the runtime error stopping the flow.  It is driving me crazy!

```
Option Explicit
Public leaders_col As New Collection
Public cavalry_dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Public infantry_dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Public artillery_dic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Public defenses_col As New Collection

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim cell_str As String
    Dim subCell_str As String
    
    For i = 7 To 11
        cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
        leaders_col.Add cell_str
    Next i
    For i = 17 To 26
        subCell_str = ""
        If IsEmpty(Range("F" & i)) Then
            cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
            For j = i + 1 To i + 10
                If Not IsEmpty(Range("F" & j)) And IsEmpty(Range("B" & j)) Then
                    If j = i + 1 Then
                        subCell_str = "D" & CStr(j)
                    Else
                        subCell_str = subCell_str & ",D" & CStr(j)
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
                i = j
            Next j
        Else
            cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
        End If        
        cavalry_dic.Add cell_str, subCell_str    
    Next i
    For i = 30 To 53
        subCell_str = ""
        If IsEmpty(Range("F" & i)) Then
            cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
            For j = i + 1 To i + 10
                If Not IsEmpty(Range("F" & j)) And IsEmpty(Range("B" & j)) Then
                    If j = i + 1 Then
                        subCell_str = "D" & CStr(j)
                    Else
                        subCell_str = subCell_str & ",D" & CStr(j)
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
                i = j
            Next j
        Else
            cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
        End If      
        infantry_dic.Add cell_str, subCell_str     
    Next i
    For i = 57 To 70
        subCell_str = ""
        If IsEmpty(Range("F" & i)) Then
            'Add the unit as a main unit
            cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
            For j = i + 1 To i + 10
                If Not IsEmpty(Range("F" & j)) And IsEmpty(Range("B" & j)) Then
                    If j = i + 1 Then
                        subCell_str = "D" & CStr(j)
                    Else
                        subCell_str = subCell_str & ",D" & CStr(j)
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
                i = j
            Next j
        Else
            cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
        End If      
        artillery_dic.Add cell_str, subCell_str    
    Next i
    For i = 76 To 80
        cell_str = "C" & CStr(i)
        defenses_col.Add cell_str
    Next i  
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you going to access `Dict` and `Collection` object from other modules? If not, the variables should be declared as `Dim leaders_col As New Collection` in Workbook_Open() .   If yes, the public variables should be declared in the standard module instead of `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: Yes they are used throughout the project.  I'm fairly new to VBA.  What is the reason for not declaring the variables in the Workbook module?

Comment: Public variables in standard modules have a lifetime that extends throughout the entire execution of the application. This makes them suitable for storing values that need to persist across different parts of your program.

Comment: As for the solution to my problem, I am embarrassed to admit that I spent about three hours on a simple problem of coding.  I was placed on the wrong path by backups that I thought were working, but evidently weren't-- I had a screwed up iteration variable in the wrong place that sent the program down a rabbit hole.  It is now fixed, and it had nothing to do with some weird VBA quirk.

Comment: taller-- is there a good place to go to learn about the differences between Standard modules, workbooks and other basic things?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  believe your Error Warnings, lol.  It was a simple problem with addition that didn't work like I thought it should. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in VBA have different scopes.

- Public variables in `standard modules` have a lifetime that extends throughout the entire execution of the application. This makes them suitable for storing values that need to persist across different parts of your program.
- If multiple procedures share variables, those variables should be defined as `module variables`. For example, use `Dim leaders_col As New Collection` at the top of the `ThisWorkbook` module.
- Otherwise, you should define the variable within a specific procedure. For example, use `Dim leaders_col As New Collection` at the beginning of the procedure (eg. `Workbook_Open()`) where it is used.